# bash: syntax error near unexpected token `

Tags: bash, syntax

I am trying to make an alias to call my linter before commit to git.

I have a bash issue and i don't understand where is the issue.

Pre-requisits to test :

- pip install sqlfluff
- go on git test project where you have no SQL files inside.
- checkout -b 'test_branch'
- create a dummy .SQL file (ex select * from test group by 1,2,3)
- create aliases and `source ~/.bashrc` if you put aliases in it.
- Use SQLlint "write a commit comment"

Alias issues:

```
alias lint="git add . && git diff HEAD --name-only --diff-filter=d | grep '.*.sql$' | xargs sqlfluff lint --dialect bigquery"

alias SQLlint="f() {branch=$(git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD); lint && git add . && git commit -m "$1" && git push -u origin $branch;};f"
```

Error:

> bash: syntax error near unexpected token `{branch=test_branch'

It is based on this blog article:
https://www.emgoto.com/magic-command/

Thank you for your time.

Comment: you're defining a function inside an alias? why so? BTW, `{` need a space around it

Comment: @Fravadona The OP saw a syntax of Git aliases somewhere on the Net and applied it wrongly to Bash aliases.

Comment: @Fravadona thanks a lot for this syntax trick ! you fixed my issue andmy alias. Thanks you to notice me it is a bad practice. I will create a function from this code now. Regards !

Comment: Your alias is defined with double quotes, which means that the variable substition occurs first: `branch` is expanded to the value at the point of the alias definition. The same applies to `$(git ....)`. You are probably wanting to have this executed when the alias is **called**, not when it is **defined**.